# statetransition while using two Arrays

Tags: c++

I'm using two c++ 2-dimensional Arrays A1 & A2. Lets say, that A1 should represent the initial state and A1 = A2 (just in the first round !). Next I want to use A1 to save the old state and A2 to save the current state of an machine.

My Problems are: 
- how can I overwrite values of A2 ? 
- how can I overwrite the state of A1 with the state of  A2 after finish a round.

My previous attempt: I just used such values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std; 


class Machine {

public:
// attributes
    int x, j;
int const constexpr static size = 2;
int A1[size][size];
int A2[size][size];
// functions

// creategrid: user sets the state at the beginning
auto creategrid() {
    for (x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            std::cout << "1 or 0";
            printf("\n");
            std::cin >> A1[x][j];
        }
    }
}
    auto statetransition() {
    int a, m;
    for (a = 0; a < size; a++) {
        for (m = 0; m < size; m++) {
            if (A1[a][m] == 0) {
                A2[a][m] = 1;
            }
            A2[a][m] = 0;
            printf("%d ", A2[a][m]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
};
int main(){
Machine MA; 
MA.createfield();
MA.statetransition(); 
}
```

Problem is, that there are no changes applied in A2.

Comment: your real code having two braces less than the code you show here could explain why you get unexpected results. Note that one brace being present or not can change the meaning of your full program. Please read about [mcve] and make sure the code you show here matches the behaviour you describe. If you do have compiler errors then you need to include them in the question

Comment: A2[a][m] is always set to 0. I guess an `else` is missing just before

Comment: If the goal is to copy a matrix to another, using vector or vector of vectors will simplify your life

Comment: Take a look at `std::array`. It probably does exactly what you want right out of the box.

Comment: Why not performing a std::swap instead of a copy ?

Comment: sorry, some thinks went wrong when copying my code from the Editor.

Comment: okey, now it should bring my Problem near to the Point. Please consider, this is just a part of my Project and I'm new in c++. I even don't know many Moduls.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy one array into another using [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

```
memcpy(A1, A2, sizeof(A1));
```

Comment: While your answer might provide a solution for the OP's problem, it doesn't well explain why the code example posted doesn't work as intended.